# Accessing a class attribute by user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to Python and I just started working with classes. I want to make a sort of Chemistry Calculator (calculates molar mass, concentration and so on). I hope I got everything right so far. My question is: ( I hope I express myself correctly) How do I call a class instantiation by user input?

I have the following class:

```
class Elements:
def __init__(self, name='',atomic_mass=0.0):
    self.name = name
    self.atomic_mass = atomic_mass
```

and I (hope that I put this correctly) instantiate it like this:

```
nitrogen = N = Elements('Nitrogen', 14.01)
```

I wrote `nitrogen` and `N` because I figured if the user input would like to call it `nitrogen` or `N` the same thing would show up. Also, is this the best way to do this? I am half way through doing to all the elements, with almost all their properties.

Now, for myself, I can do :`print(N.atomic_mass)` and I would get `14.01`
Regarding my question, how would I achieve something like this:

```
element_name = input('Insert element name: ')
print(element_name.atomic_mass)
```

and then get the wanted value. I need to this because If I want to calculate the mass of a molecule by user input it would be necessary to split the string, find the elements and link them to the attribute.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891979/accessing-a-class-instances-attributes-using-user-input) and it did not work.
I know that I could probably do it with:

```
if element_name == 'N':
print(N.atomic_mass)
```

But having to do this for 118 elements of the period table seems a lot. Well I could do it but I believe there **has** to be a better, easier way.

Is it even possible to do what I ask? Thank you.

Comment: The user shouldn't know or care about what variable names you are using. You want a *dict* of elements: `elements = {}; elements['N'] = elements['nitrogen'] = Element('Nitrogen', 14.01)`.

Comment: @chepner I just read today about dictionaries but it did not even cross my mind I could use them with functions. Thank you !!

Comment: You're just assigning the result of a function call to the dictionary. (Although it is also true that you can store a function itself in a dictionary, but that's not happening here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a class instance for each element, you could maybe use a `dict`.
(the order doesn't matter, because 'dict's do not preserve the order)
This dict could hold the values directly, or the `Element` instances

```
elements = {
    'Nitrogen': 14.01,
    'Carbon': 12.0,
    ...
}
```

or

```
elements = {
    'Nitrogen': Element('Nitrogen', 14.01),
    ...
}
```

Then you could use it this way:

```
element_name = input('Insert element name: ')
print('atomic mass:', elements[element_name])
```

Note: this may raise `KeyError` if the user inputs an invalid element, so you can add error checking

```
element_name = input('Insert element name: ')
try:
    print('atomic mass:', elements[element_name])
except KeyError:
    print('the element does not exist')
```